# Function in bash to commit and push in one command

Tags: git, bash

I try to commit and push in one command, typing something like:

`gm "This is my commit message"`

Which would run:

`git commit -am "This is my commit message" && git push`

I've tried this function in my `.bashrc`:

```
function gm() {
     git commit -am $1 && git push
}
```

Which works, except for the fact that I can not type several words as commit message. I can run

`gm My_Message`

and it works fine, but if  I type several words, like

`gm This is my message`

It will only run `git commit -am "This" && git push`. I tried using quotation marks but it returns an error. How should I configure this function to work?

Comment: This is a bad idea. Situations will inevitably arise where this bites you

Comment: If you really want to do this (like Daenyth said, you probably don't), why not use an alias? You can embed the function (e.g. `gm = "!f() { ... }; f"`) and then invoke it as `git gm`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need quotes around both the place calling the function and the git command.

```
function gm() {
     git commit -am "$1" && git push
}

gm "This is my message"
```

An alternative approach is:

```
function gm() {
     git commit -am "$*" && git push
}

gm This is my message
```

But this will mean that:

```
gm This commit  has double  spaced sections.\t And a tab, \
and a new line
```

(Where \t is actually a tab)
will give the commit message of:

```
This commit has double spaced sections. And a tab, and a new line
```

So all the white space is collapsed.

Also, if you want to enter a more complicated and complete commit message, you might want to you `$EDITOR` and omit `-m` entirely.

Also, you aren't really using the power of distributed version control if you immediately push every commit.

Comment: You don't need to add qutoes to $1 inside the function.

Comment: @Griffin Are you sure? - the git man page doesn't suggest that msg can have multiple arguments.

Comment: I had to add the quotes, otherwise I got a weird message about the -a being invalid, something like that.

Comment: "Also, you aren't really using the power of distributed version control if you immediately push every commit." The workflow pattern of pushing after every commit is still useful if I'm the only one working on a project, right? Or if I'm only pushing to my branch/fork?

Comment: @SamarthChawla You can do that, but you could equally do that with subversion or any other centralised source control system. One of the advantages of distributed source control is that you can work when you are disconnected. Also with git, unpublished commits can be edited, to make your revision history easier to understand. If you push to a shared repository, then you can't rewrite those commits.

Answer (score 6):

## New, expanded answer

- This is closest to what you're asking for:

  git commit -am "$*" && git push

$1 specifically means the first argument in a (whitespace-seperated) list.

NB. I originally wrote "$@", but that expands to "$1" "$2" ..., which isn't what you want: "$*" expands to a single quoted string with all arguments.

- Simply quoting the string yourself may be more sensible, especially if you care about the shell chomping whitespace (so run `gm "my commit message"` and use the `"$1"` syntax Douglas describes)
- Using an external editor is best if you *really* care about formatting.  Just omit the `-m` argument entirely, make sure `$EDITOR` is set to something you like to use, and take a look at this [note about git commit messages](http://tbaggery.com/2008/04/19/a-note-about-git-commit-messages.html).

Comment: The only problem with this approach (splitting by whitespace for arguments to the function, then recombining them for the git command), is that all white-space is squashed to a single space.

Comment: True, although if you really care about the formatting of your message, you're better off writing it in an editor anwyay.

Comment: git commit -am will not add new files, so git add -A && git commit -m "$*" && git push

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, a better approach would be:

```
git config --global alias.acp '!f() { git add -A && git commit -m "$@" && git push; }; f'
```

which will set an alias named `acp` for native git command.

Now you can easily run `git acp "commit messages here!"`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have you encapsulate the words with quotes, like `gm "this is my message"`.