# git add, commit and push commands in one?

Tags: git

Is there any way to use these three commands in one?

```
git add .
git commit -a -m "commit" (do not need commit message either)
git push
```

Sometimes I'm changing only one letter, CSS padding or something. Still, I have to write all three commands to push the changes. There are many projects where I'm only one pusher, so this command would be awesome!

Comment: Have you tried writing a shell script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852148/function-in-bash-to-commit-and-push-in-one-command

Comment: There are a lot of changes in my code, when you are changing just a padding in css, or one letter and etc. Commit messages and all these commands stuff adds a lot of work.
Not tried a shell script. How it can be done? Thanks!

Comment: "(do not need commit message either)" http://images.wikia.com/dragonball/images/a/a7/Facepalm_227785.jpg

Comment: if you are doing a commit for every single instance of a change, you are doing it wrong. do the command's when you're feature is finished or bug is solved (this could be a single change)

Comment: For anybody stumbling across this question, you should never `git add .` or `git add -a`. This is the source of so much trouble, for so many people. Use `git add -p` or `git add -i`, both of which allow you to examine each change you're adding, and respond with `Y/N` to add or skip that change. This prevents you from adding entire files that shouldn't have been added, or specific changes like `console.log`/`binding.pry`/etc. that you didn't meant to commit.

Comment: Yes. Except, `lazygit` is way too much to type! Let's call it `lg`.

Answer (score 340):

Building off of @Gavin's answer:

Making lazygit a function instead of an alias allows you to pass it an argument. I have added the following to my .bashrc (or .bash_profile if Mac):

```
function lazygit() {
    git add .
    git commit -a -m "$1"
    git push
}
```

This allows you to provide a commit message, such as

```
lazygit "My commit msg"
```

You could of course beef this up even more by accepting even more arguments, such as which remote place to push to, or which branch.

Comment: Not working on my ubuntu server, is there something more I should do like a reboot or something? I added your function to the end of my .bashrc script.

Comment: @JoeYahchouchi Not working how? Have you reset your terminal (or resourced the bashrc file)? What happens if you type `which lazygit`?

Comment: Never mind it works, and thank you. A server restart did the trick, I wanted to modify my comment but I could not find it.

Comment: Restart not needed, just do  "source .bashrc"

Comment: could use `$*` instead of `$1` to save typing the quotes: `lazygit My commit msg`

Comment: @KaiCarver Nice thought, but personally I do not like it. It prevents you from using multiple args, and also goes against the normal convention of a single string arg with spaces being wrapped in quotes. This is second nature to me at this point (and I would assume a lot of developers). Leaving out the quotes feels dirty.

Comment: lazygit, best name ever!

Comment: @btse I'm pretty sure this git command/workflow also goes against the git conventions/philosophy :P

Comment: Wonderful! works like a charm on mac. I'm getting really lazy :)

Comment: @btse me being a diplomatic person + it's friday. Here is the function using @KaiCarver suggestion: 
`function dirtygit() {
    git add .
    git commit -a -m "$*"
    git push
}`

Comment: @OnklMaps nice, but since stackoverflow comments don’t allow new lines, best put in semicolons: `function dirtygit() { git add . ; git commit -a -m "$*" ; git push }`

Comment: You can use zsh-autopair to close your quotes, parenthesis etc.

Comment: `Making lazygit a function instead of an alias allows you to pass it an argument`: what do you mean exactly? Is it really impossible to pass an argument with an alias?

Comment: If someone would have told me that in 2007, I would have saved some typing time.

Comment: Oh, indeed, you can pass arguments to git shell aliases, please see today's update to my answer!

Comment: Using git on Windows 10 here. The lazygit function works for me from the git bash but when I try to run it from command prompt using `git lazygit "Testing alias from cmd"`, it says `lazygit is not a git command`. Any ideas? I usually use the command prompt for most of the terminal work

Comment: Is there a way to have a default commit message, in case user does not provide any argument #1 after `lazygit`? Thanks!!

Comment: Pro tip: if like me you're too lazy to type `lazygit`, I recommend to use `glz`. Don't check, it isn't in conflict with the Oh-My-Zsh git plugin.

Comment: Use %1 without the double quotes in place of "$1" for Windows

Comment: You don't need `-a` because of using `add .`

Answer (score 129):

I ended up adding an alias to my `.gitconfig` file:

```
[alias]
    cmp = "!f() { git add -A && git commit -m \"$@\" && git push; }; f"
```

Usage: `git cmp "Long commit message goes here"`

Adds all files, then uses the comment for the commit message and pushes it up to origin.

I think it's a better solution because you have control over what the commit message is.

The alias can be also defined from command line, this adds it to your `.gitconfig`:

```
git config --global alias.cmp '!f() { git add -A && git commit -m "$@" && git push; }; f'
```

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for! Works perfectly, thanks! I couldn't find a full syntax reference or a detailed list of commands. What does `!f() { ... }; f`do exactly? More explanation of that line would make the answer even better.

Comment: @DmitriyDemir It defines the function `f`, then calls it.

Comment: Works really well. I added `git pull` to the start so that merges are reduced.

Comment: @Oliver Why is it in quotes? Why is there an exclamation point? Does the f at the end call the function? What is "$@"?

Comment: @PhilipRego Wrong Oliver :p

Comment: @Oliver Right Oliver

Comment: issue in VSCode powershell, i cant add space to commit message :( git cmp "spaces wont work" so i have to add dashes in-between. let me know brightheads if there's some way

Comment: @JerryGoyal On Windows, you may need to escape the double quotes around $1 to get it to work from PowerShell (using ... \"$1\" ...)

Answer (score 88):

While I agree with Wayne Werner on his doubts, this is technically an option:

```
git config alias.acp '! git commit -a -m "commit" && git push'
```

Which defines an alias that runs `commit` and `push`. Use it as `git acp`. Please be aware that such "shell" aliases are always run from the root of your git repository.

Another option might be to write a post-commit hook that does the push.

Oh, by the way, you indeed *can* pass arguments to shell aliases. If you want to pass a custom commit message, instead use:

```
git config alias.acp '! acp() { git commit -a -m "$1" && git push ; } ; acp'
```

(Of course, now, you will need to give a commit message: `git acp "My message goes here!"`)

Comment: @wlz I just tried it and it works fine. Note that the whole string is inside single-quotes. `git` automatically added the escapes (checked with `git config -e`).

Comment: Sorry , you're right :) . I directly edit the .gitconfig file . The " has already escaped with \" .

Comment: Why isn't this the accepted answer? It does what was asked. +1.

Comment: On Windows, I needed to escape the double quotes around $1 to get it to work from PowerShell (using ... \"$1\" ...)

Comment: Please update with an answer that works on windows as well

Answer (score 49):

I use this in my .bash_profile

```
gitpush() {
    git add .
    git commit -m "$*"
    git push
}
alias gp=gitpush
```

It executes like

```
gp A really long commit message
```

Don't forget to run `source ~/.bash_profile` after saving the alias.

Comment: I really like this. ...and have therefore adopted it into my own ~/.bash_profile ;) thanks.. +1

Comment: Careful on the alias `gp`. It would conflict with Oh-My-Zsh's git plugin, where `gp` is used to `git push`

Answer (score 44):

I think you might misunderstand the workflow that git was designed for. (To clarify/correct what I meant in the comment, you don't need the `git add .`, since `commit -a` usually serves the same purpose - adding any changes that have not yet been staged, if the files have already been added)

Typically you'll do something like this:

```
# make some changes
$ git commit -a -m "Changed something"
# make some more changes
$ git commit -a -m "Changed something else"
```

wash, rinse, repeat, until you've finished feature X, or you're at a stopping point, or you just want other people to see what you've done. Then you do

```
$ git push
```

Git is not SVN - but it appears that you're trying to use it as such. You might find some of the resources at the end of the article [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-git-subversion-1/) to be of some use.

Comment: +1 for the explanation about the workflow. However `git add .` and `git commit -a` [are not the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541647/git-add-vs-git-commit-a)

Comment: If I'm deleting/creating a file. Does `git commit -a` finds it? For me it fails, but maybe something wrong has been done

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but GIT will not collapse if there will be a command like this for those who knows what they are doing...

Comment: My bad - I don't use git as much as I would like to - I corrected my answer. Unless you're constantly adding & removing files it seems like `git add .` should still be a fairly rare command (maybe 10-50 times for a reasonably large project?)

Comment: @Lucas: Experienced programmers will tell you that people who ask for an automatic commit-push command don't know what they're doing. There's a reason for the 3-stage code checkin (if you're using feature branches, 4-stage).

Comment: @slebetman: there might be some exceptions to this rule where you can't simulate dev env. locally. For eg., we must deploy to real internet server when developing facebook apps. With svn, we have commit to deploy script configured. What's your suggestion for git?

Comment: @SenG: In git we use push to deploy configured scripts.

Comment: @slebetman: I didn't explain it correctly. With facebook apps, every single change must be deployed to live server even for development. So, we have setup commit hooks to do that. You do a change, commit it and see the change in your app. With git, I need to add, stage then push it to see a single change. Doesn't it look a overkill?

Comment: @SenG: Weather or not you consider it overkill does not matter. It's just how it git works. I've developed facebook apps and all my unit test scripts don't need facebook to run. If you need facebook to do testing then you're not doing it right. Of course, you need facebook for integration testing. But you don't need to do integration testing to test your code. Hence my statement stands: experienced programmers will tell you that you don't need to push to test your code.

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to commit to test your code, either.  You should write some code, test it, and *then* commit and push.  The legendary use of local git commits to provide some sort of multi-file "undo" functionality is used far more in legend than in reality, in my experience.

Comment: @JoeStrout I personally use it far more when I'm prototyping (i.e. I'm trying to have an idea what I'm doing) than when actually developing code.

Comment: Although I agree, OP's situation does arrive very often, typically, when pushing the last version of a pull request, and noticing right after an extra blank line. In those scenarios, we should be able to just add / commit / push quickly.

Answer (score 40):

You can use bash script , set alias to launch any command or group of commands

```
git commit -am "your message" && git push
```

Comment: If you wish to make this an answer, please add more commentary around how it works. Answers which are simply a code dump are generally not well received. See [answer].

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer. As it answer the question as succinctly as possible. Just type it into terminal and it works! If you doesn't want to add an alias an alternative would be to simply create a textExpander expand and trigger it via a key-combo.

Comment: Works beautifully. I think this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 24):

Simpliest solution would be to:

```
git commit -a -m "commit" && git push
```

`git add` is already contained in -a parameter of commit, but if you want you can connect them all:

```
git add . && git commit -a -m "commit" && git push
```

Comment: love it. worth considering the addition of `git pull &` as the first step as well

Comment: git add is not included in the `-a`, particularly for the untracked files:  *-a, --all
    Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you
    have not told git about are not affected.*

Answer (score 21):

Set as an alias in bash:

```
$ alias lazygit="git add .; git commit -a -m '...'; git push;";
```

Call it:

```
$ lazygit
```

(To make this alias permanent, you'd have to include it in your .bashrc or .bash_profile)

Comment: You would need it add that alias to .bashrc or .bash_profile to make it permanent

Comment: I think this page can help to explain: http://serverfault.com/questions/3743/what-useful-things-can-one-add-to-ones-bashrc

Answer (score 11):

In Linux/Mac, this much practical option should also work

```
git commit -am "IssueNumberIAmWorkingOn --hit Enter key
> A detail here --Enter
> Another detail here --Enter
> Third line here" && git push --last Enter and it will be there
```

If you are working on a **new** branch created locally, change the `git push` piece with `git push -u origin branch_name`

If you want to edit your commit message in system editor then

```
git commit -a && git push
```

will open the editor and once you save the message it will also push it.

Answer (score 9):

You can try [gitu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-upload).

For the first time (node js has to be installed):

```
npm install -g git-upload
```

After that:

```
gitu COMMIT_MSG
```

To issue those three commands at once.

The good thing is that you **don't have to worry when you reinstall your system or when you want to do this on different computers and No file modification is needed.**
This also **work on different platforms** (not just Linux and Mac, but also Windows under command prompt like `cmd` and `powershell`) just that you have to install `npm` and `nodejs` (`git` of course).

Answer (score 7):

If the file is already being tracked then you do not need to run `git add`, you can simply write `git commit -am 'your message'`

If you do not want to write a commit message you might consider doing something like

`git commit --allow-empty-message -am ''`

Answer (score 7):

If you're using a Mac:

1. Start up Terminal and input `cd ~/` to go to your home folder
2. Type `touch .bash_profile` to create your new file.
3. Edit `.bash_profile` with your favourite editor (or you can just type
   `open -e .bash_profile` to open it in TextEdit).
4. Copy & Paste the below into the file:

> ```
> function lazygit() {
>     git add .
>     git commit -a -m "$1"
>     git push
> }
> ```

After this, restart your terminal and simply add, commit and push in one easy command, example:

```
lazygit "This is my commit message"
```

Answer (score 5):

[This Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp98E.jpg)
- **Try this:** Simple script one command for git add, git commit and git push

Open your CMD on Windows and paste this answer

`git commit -m "your message" . && git push origin master`

> This example my picture screenshot :
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IZDe.jpg

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4299159/2134166) answer, you can create a **git alias** and assign a set of commands for it. In this case, it would be:

```
git config --global alias.add-com-push '!git add . && git commit -a -m "commit" && git push'
```

and use it with

```
git add-com-push
```

Comment: This doesn't add anything to any of the previous answers.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right. I think I didn't notice that Tilman Vogel's answer was the same as mine.. Should I delete it??

Answer (score 4):

I like to run the following:

```
git commit -am "message";git push
```

Comment: I think the `;` should be replaced with `&&` in your command, since the later will execute the `git push` command only if there's no error on the previous command(s).

Answer (score 4):

For the macOS users:

1. Open your **Terminal** or **iTerm2** or another terminal that you use.
2. Move to your User profile folder with command `~/`. It's a default folder for `.bash_profile` file:

[image: User folder example]

2. Type `nano .bash_profile` This command will open the `.bash_profile` document (or create it if it doesn’t already exist) in the easiest to use text editor for terminal – `nano`.
3. Now you can make a simple change to the file. Paste these lines of code to change your Terminal prompt:

```
function lazygit() {
    git add .
    git commit -a -m "$1"
    git push
}
```

[image: Nano text editing]

4. Now save your changes by typing `ctrl + o` and hit return to save. Then exit `nano` by typing `ctrl + x`.
5. Now we need to activate your changes. Type `source .bash_profile` (or `. ~/.bash_profile`) and watch your prompt change.
6. In iTerm2 `Preferences/Profiles/General/Command` set to `Login Shell` and `Send text at start` to `source ~/.bash_profile`. So you don't need to make it manually after each macOS restart.
   [image: iTerm 2 preferences]

Credentials: https://natelandau.com/my-mac-osx-bash_profile

Answer (score 3):

I use a batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /p comment=Comment:
git add *
git commit -a -m "%comment%"
git push
```

Comment: probs would be easier if you accepted in args from the command line. i simply go "lezygit MESSAGE" etc. its pretty cool!

Answer (score 3):

Write a small script named gitpush.sh with below lines and add it your ~ directory.

```
echo $1
git add .
git commit -m "$1"
git push
```

Now add an alias in ~/.bashrc like below :

```
alias gitpush='~/gitpush'
```

Now from any git repository just write gitpush "message" .

Answer (score 2):

For MAC VSC users the best setup is:

1) press 'shift+cmd+P' and type:

```
Shell Command: install 'code' command in PATH
```

Press ENTER (this will install code command to get to the bash_profile easily)

2 ) you can now run: `code ~/.bash_profile` to open the empty bash_profile

3) enter a new function in there:

```
function lazygit() {
    git add .
    git commit -m "$*"
    git push
}
```

4) now restart VSC

5) make a change, save it and type `lazygit message` to run the three commands concurrently

Answer (score 2):

Please see my answer,I added everything into a single line

```
alias gitcomm="echo 'Please enter commit message';read MSG ;git add --all;git commit -am=$MSG;git push"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the scripts above:

shift "removes" the parameter $1, otherwise, "push" will read it and "misunderstand it".

My tip :

> git config --global alias.acpp '!git add -A && branchatu="$(git
>   symbolic-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null)" && branchatu=${branchatu##refs/heads/}
>   && git commit -m "$1" && shift && git pull -u origin $branchatu && git
>   push -u origin $branchatu'

Answer (score 1):

When you want svn-like behavior of git commit, use this in your git aliases in your .gitconfig

`commit = "!f() { git commit \"$@\" && git push; };f"`

Answer (score 1):

Building off the [`lazygit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23328996/1071884) answer, the following solution adds a user check to verify the changes before pushing.  It will revert the commands if cancelled.  And all that will happen if and only if there are changes in the local repo.

```
### SAFER LAZY GIT
function lazygit() {
  git add .
  if git commit -a -m "$1"; then
    read -r -p "Are you sure you want to push these changes? [y/N]} " response
    case "$response" in
      [yY][eE][sS]|[yY])
        git push
        ;;
      *)
        git reset HEAD~1 --soft
        echo "Reverted changes."
        ;;
    esac
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using fish shell (building off of btse's answer):

Save this file within '~/.config/fish/functions' as 'quickgit.fish'. Create the directory if it does not exist.
'--git-dir=$PWD/.git' Ensures that we run the git commands against the git project where we called the function

```
function quickgit # This is the function name and command we call
    git --git-dir=$PWD/.git add . # Stage all unstaged files
    git --git-dir=$PWD/.git commit -a -m $argv # Commit files with the given argument as the commit message
    git --git-dir=$PWD/.git push # Push to remote
end
```

Restart terminal, navigate to project, make changes, and now you can call 'quickgit "example message"'.
Changes will now be added, committed, and push :).

Also can be found as a Gist here: https://gist.github.com/Abushawish/3440a6087c212bd67ce1e93f8d283a69

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of good solutions already, but here's a solution that I find more elegant for the way I want to work:

I put a script in my path called "git-put" that contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
git commit "$@" && git push -u
```

That allows me to run:

> git put -am"my commit message"

..to add all files, commit them, and push them.

(I also added the "-u" because I like to do this anyway, even though it's not related to this issue. It ensures that the upstream branch is always set up for pulling.)

I like this approach because it also allows to to use "git put" without adding all the files (skip the "-a"), or with any other options I might want to pass to commit. Also, "put" is a short portmanteau of "push" and "commit"

Answer (score 1):

If you use VSCode, you can download [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alfredbirk.git-add-commit-push) extension which will let you do it in one simple keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Hello  you have just to add un alias with  [nano or vi] ~/.bashrc

```
echo Enter You commit message && read msg && git add . && git commit -m "$msg" && git push origin main
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: works nicely. btw: usually `git push` at the end will be sufficient. And I would put `Enter ... message` in quotation marks, just for style reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I did this .sh script for command

```
#!/bin/sh
cd LOCALDIRECTORYNAME/  
git config --global user.email "YOURMAILADDRESS"
git config --global user.name "YOURUSERNAME"
git init
git status
git add -A && git commit -m "MASSAGEFORCOMMITS"
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question doesn't specify which shell, here's the eshell version based on the earlier answers.  This goes in the eshell alias file, which might be in ~/.emacs.d/eshell/alias   I've added the first part z https://github.com/rupa/z/  which let's you quickly cd to a directory, so that this can be run no matter what your current directory is.

```
alias census z cens; git add .; git commit -m "fast"; git push
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in `~/.bash_profile` for adding, committing and pushing with one command put:

```
function g() { git commit -a -m "$*"; git push; }
```

Usage:

```
g your commit message
g your commit message 'message'
```

No quotes are needed although you can't use semicolons or parenthesis in your commit messages (single quotes are allowed). If you want to any of these just simply put double quotes in you message, e.g.:

```
g "your commit message; (message)"
```

To create a comment in your message do:

```
g "your commit message:
> your note"
```

There's also a function for adding and committing in a similar way:

```
function c() { git add --all; git commit -m "$*"; }
```

Works exactly the same way that `g` function and has the same constraints. Just put `c` instead.
E.g.

```
c your commit message
```

You can also add an alias for pushing to the remote:

```
alias p='git push'
```

Usage:

```
p
```

That amounts into 2 letters, `c` and `p` you use while working with your git repository. Or you can use `g` instead to do it all with only one letter.

Full list of aliases and functions:
https://gist.github.com/matt360/0c5765d6f0579a5aa74641bc47ae50ac

Answer (score 0):

This is perfect for command grouping.

[Grouping Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html#Command-Grouping)

> { list; }
>   Placing a list of commands between curly braces causes the list to be executed in the current shell context. No subshell is created. The semicolon (or newline) following list is required.

```
legit(){ git add --all; git commit -m "$1"; git push origin master; }
legit 'your commit message here'
```

Comment: This won't work if commit message has spaces in between

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://github.com/atongen/yolo) `yolo` alias to be amazing to even submit a random comment to the commit while I am being lazy. It works really well out of the box, so I just do `git yolo` and all my changes are pushed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

define function in .bashrc

```
function gitall() {
    file=${1:-.}
    comment=${2:-update}
    echo $file
    echo $comment
    git add $file && git commit -m '$comment' && git push origin master
}
```

in your terminal

```
gitall
```

default gitall will add all in current git repo

```
gitall some-file-to-add 'update file'
```

will add certain file to change, and use custom commit message

Answer (score 0):

I created a dedicated bash script for automating these all, as it gives me a lot of trouble every time.

It looks like this

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# Shell Script to add all files, commit them with a commit message from user and then push them to remote GitHub repo
echo "*** Automating Git Add, Commit and Push ***"

#Ask for Username
echo "Enter your GitHub username: "
read username

#Ask for User Github's personal access token
echo "Enter your GitHub personal access token: "
read token

# Ask for repository name
echo "Enter repository name"
read repoName
# Check if repository exists at GitHub
curl "https://api.github.com/repos/${username}/${repoName}.git"
# If repository exits then

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    cd $repoName
    # Display unstaged files
    git status
    git remote set-url origin https://${token}@github.com/${username}/${repoName}.git
    # If there are any uncommited and unstatged files, ask user to commit them
    if [ "$(git status --porcelain)" ]; then
        echo "There are uncommited and unstatged files. Commit them before pushing"
        echo "Enter commit message"
        read commitMessage
        git add .
        git commit -m "$commitMessage"
        git push
        echo "Files pushed to GitHub"
        # else push all commited and staged files to remote repo
    else
        git push
        echo "Files pushed to GitHub"
        
    fi
    #Echo message if there is no files to commit, stage or push
    if [ "$(git status --porcelain)" ]; then
        echo "There are no files to commit, stage or push"
    fi
else
    echo "Repository does not exist"
fi


# End of script
```

You can simply use it by making a script.sh (or whatever you want to name in) BASH Script, it uses GitHub's Personal Acces Token to authenticate, if you don't have one already, you can find how to get on using [this](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) official Documentation.

I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).