# Git commit and push in Netbeans in one command

Tags: git, netbeans

Is there a way to automatically push changes in git to the remote repository every time I commit to the local one in Netbeans, similar to [git add, commit and push commands in one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595067/git-add-commit-and-push-commands-in-one)?

Comment: You almost certainly do not want to automate such a push. Do you never need to amend a commit?

Comment: @Jubobs I am a one-man team, so if I need to amend it, I can just push again. I basically push to keep it backed up off my computer just in case anything happens to my computer.

Comment: @clum Exactly my problem, situation and worry.

Comment: I need exactly the same thing.. any news on that?

Comment: @elect - I never found a way to do it, but I haven't looked into it since.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [bug 211451](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=211451) keep track of that feature request, which is not yet available in NBetBeans:

- eGit provides a separate button "Commit and Push".
- IDEA provides a button labeled "Commit" which acts like a dropdown. When the dropdown is opened then the actions "Commit and push", "Export as patch" are available.

Since NetBeans-Git is using [JGit](https://eclipse.org/jgit/), a post-commit hook wouldn't work ([not supported yet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6232026/6309)).