# git add commit push one liner for powershell windows

Tags: windows, git, powershell

I am looking for a single command where I can `add` `commit` & `push` using new [Powershell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) for Windows.
Single command like `lazygit my commit msg` // I'd prefer w/o quotes if possible

I looked over few questions on SO like [git add, commit and push commands in one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595067/git-add-commit-and-push-commands-in-one) which provided solution but for `bash`:

```
function lazygit() {
    git add .
    git commit -a -m "$*"
    git push
} 
//use it like lazygit my commit msg
```

Another answer suggested a git alias: `git config --global alias.lazy '!f() { git add -A && git commit -m "$@" && git push; }; f'`

but i have to add quotes and can't use spaces in commit message (gives error `error: pathspec 'commit message' did not match any file(s) known to git`)

---

ofcourse, there's one solution to write multiple commands in one line using `;` but I'm hoping for simple one word command

Comment: use `"$*"` to quote the entire args list as a single word, the `"$@"` in the alias is quoting each remaining argument individually.  …`'!f() { git add -A && git commit -m "$*" && git push; }; f'`.

Comment: Does replacing `"$*"` with `$args` in the function not work?

Comment: How do you feel about writing a PowerShell script to encapsulate it into a single command?

Comment: @JoshuaDrake yes please if you can provide working snippet, i'm not comfortable writing shell scripts

Comment: @jthill didn't work,gives error when providing more than single word: pathspec 'second argument' did not match any file(s) known to git

Comment: @Bill_Stewart no, error: switch `m' requires a value

Comment: @JerryGoyal Remember that we can't see your screen. Please try defining a function like above (are you familiar with how to define a function in PowerShell?) and replace `"$*"` with `$args`. Run the command with the arguments you need. If it outputs an error, paste the exact error output into your question.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I thought you mentioned to replace the variable in git config --global alias, I'll run the powershell function now

Comment: @JerryGoyal please see my answer to your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this function work for you?

```
function lazygit {
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)]
    [String[]] $message
  )
  git add .
  git commit -a -m "$message"
  git push
}
```

Running this:

```
lazygit my commit message
```

Will run these three commands:

```
git add .
git commit -a -m "my commit message"
git push
```

Comment: I didn't know that i can just paste the function in powershell to make it run, it worked but for the same session window. I think some extra work is required for making it as a global function.

Comment: Add the function to your PowerShell profile script and it will be available in all PowerShell sessions (with the exception of PowerShell sessions started with `-NoProfile`). See `help about_Profiles` for information about profile scripts.

Comment: Yup, that worked. For future readers: I opened pshell as admin, created & opened profile by executing `notepad $PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts`  and wrote the function there.