# How do I add, commit and push code to git using git bash command at once?

Tags: git, git-bash

When we want to add, commit all file at once and push on single command from git bash what is the syntax/command for it so that I don't have to type multiple command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command to add, commit all file and push to git at once:

**New approach:**

```
git commit -am "message" && git push origin branch_name
```

**Traditional:**

```
Step-1:    
git add. //for multiple file
or
git add file_name //for single file
```

Step-2:

```
git commit -m"hello message"
```

Step-3:

```
git push origin branch_name
```

Note: You can note that you don't have to write extra two command for add, commit and push if you want to do at once.

Comment: Note that `commit -am` only commits changed or deleted files. It does not commit added files. See the `-a` flag in the official [git commit reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit). [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595067) has more complete answers.